# Import bacpac database with SqlPackage, check exist and specify location

Tags: sql-server, database, import, sqlpackage, bacpac

Can I run `SqlPackage` to import `bacpac`, which can check database exist before run, and also specify where to put the `.mdf, .ldf` file? So when the database exist, it will not do anything; but if it is not existed, it will import the database for me?

Comment: I think you will have to combine T-SQL and sqlpackage.exe to achieve this. xp_cmdshell for sqlpackage.exe.

Comment: @DeanSavović I tried your solution and it worked, thank :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlPackage.exe doesn't accept arguments to specify the location of the mdf and ldf files for the import action.

There are a couple of options to work around this:

- Create an empty database with the desired mdf and ldf files yourself (using, for example, sqlcmd), and then run SqlPackage.exe to import the bacpac file into the empty database.
- Use a "deployment contributor" to modify the behavior of deployment at runtime. This is a bit complicated as it involves compiling some C# code into a .NET dll that must then be used when performing the import operation. But the nice part is that you can rewrite the T-SQL that SqlPackage.exe executes however you'd like. Here's a sample deployment contributor that modifies the data and log file paths: https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/blob/master/Samples/Contributors/DbLocationModifier.cs

As for different behavior for exists vs doesn't exist -- note that the import command will refuse to modify a non-empty database, so it's safe to execute the import operation without regard to whether the database already exists.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for my Advanced Installer project and it worked, thanks